# How to set the PATH variable using an Ansible playbook?

Tags: linux, unix, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am setting the path variable in `/etc/profile.d/script.sh`.
It is working fine, but I need to reboot my machine to trigger this script.

For every RPM I am creating the path is different, so, after installing a RPM it will create the script in `/etc/profile.d`, but, to run it, the user have to login again.
This is also problematic because it needs to be done via an Ansible playbook.

I want to set the path temporarily (in users' session) because once user logged off `/etc/profile.d` script will run anyway and it will set the path.

Comment: "_I am setting the path variable in /etc/profile.d/script.sh its working fine but I need to reboot my machine to trigger this script._", as far as I can observe in my environment just logout and login again. No reboot necessary ...

Comment: Or just source the files in the folder, even.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to set the path temporarily

You can use the [`environment` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#play), at the play level to change the path for the whole play:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  environment:
    PATH: "/extra/path/to/bin:{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}"
```

Which you can also use at a task level, e.g.:

```yaml
- command: keytool --help
  environment:
    PATH: "/path/to/java/bin:{{ lookup('env', 'PATH') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer β.εηοιτ.βε but  I have to keep gather_facts: true also this wont change the path once playbook run is completed

Comment: @VikasUpadhyay `gather_Facts: false` was just to make the example minimal. For when the playbook run is completed, as you said it, the `profile.d` scripts would do.

Comment: profile.d will do when user will relogin but we dont want users to relogin every time when they run a playbook

Comment: They don't need to re-login, they can source the files.